# Extension for a string returns unexpected value for that string in C#

Tags: c#

Maybe the question sound not good or too simple. But not for me in this case.

My problem is:
I created an extension for string, like

```
public static void SetString( this string aString, string anotherString ) {

         aString = anotherString ;

         // process info for that string ... (database, files, etc)
      }
```

If I call that extension like:

```
string anExistingString = "123";
anExistingString.SetString("Other value");

Console.Write(anExistingString);
```

but returns `123` instead of `Other value`...

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: C# does not work this way. IOW, you cannot do this at all (well you can with some tricks).

Comment: `anExistingString = "Other value";` seems waaaaaaaaaaay more readable and intuitive to any developer than `anExistingString.SetString("Other value");`. Any particular reason you wouldn't use the built-in assignment operator in C#?

Comment: I dont understand the need to do this at all when string myString = "Other value" does exactly the same thing. No need to over complicate for something that has no special function.

Comment: That was an simple example to understand but my code, the extension method has more lines than I wrote there ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible as an extension method. References to class variables are passed by value, in order to assign a new value to a value passed in a method, you'll need to use a `ref` parameter:

```
public void SetString(ref string aString, string anotherString)
{
  aString = anotherString;
}
```

Personally I consider `ref` and `out` parameters a code smell, it generally implies the method is responsible for more than one thing or is doing something that it shouldn't. In your example, assignment is far more readable than calling a method.

Comment: "Class instances are passed by reference" is incorrect - references are passed by value. There's a big difference. Please read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't phrase it particularly (or, indeed, at all) well, answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check my articl : [Extension Methods](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/11/extension-methods.html) in which i talked about string encyption extension method

You need to return value from the function that will do the work for you..

```
public static string SetString( this string aString, string anotherString)
{
    return anotherString ;
}

string anExistingString = "123";
anExistingString = anExistingString.SetString("Other value");
```

Comment: can show me an example ? I tried with return but ... maybe my implementation is not good ...

Comment: Why to wirte anExistingString = anExistingString.SetString("Other value"); rather then anExistingString = "Other value";

Comment: @Asif - i m thinking same way this operation can be done without writing the extension method but i think he want to learn what extesion method and than going to try anything else ...

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour in .net when a function is called that would alter the original value, is to have the value returned and re-assign that value (for example, substring does not alter the value, but returns the altered value).
(Now you could have a static procedure with a *ref* parameter, but that's not possible with an extension method)

```
public static string SetString( this string aString, string anotherString ) {    
        //process logic here
        return anotherSTring;
 }

 //call
string anExistingString = "123";
anExistingString  = anExistingString.SetString("Other value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling `String.Copy` method:

```
public static void SetString(this string aString, string anotherString )
 {        
      aString = string.Copy(anotherString);       
 }
```

Comment: Not work, they (who posted the answers) have right. Cannot using extension to alter original string value